# updating array of objects in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongoose

record in db collection

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23d"), 
"students" : [
    {
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a56fd3a02a50271d233a92f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23f")
    }, 
    {
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a65ce5cc0533638e4e2df3f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23e")
    }
]
```

i had this record. now i want to update this student array of object with this record

values to update

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23d"), 
"students" : [
    {
        "comments" : "not bad", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(50), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a56fd3a02a50271d233a92f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f5")
    }, 
    {
        "comments" : "good", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(100), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a65ce5cc0533638e4e2df3f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f4")
    }
]
```

when i try with this query it adds extra fields to the array

### node js

```
student.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: req.body.id
}, {
  "$addToSet": {
    "students": {
      "$each": [
    {
        "comments" : "not bad", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(50), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a56fd3a02a50271d233a92f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f5")
    }, 
    {
        "comments" : "good", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(100), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a65ce5cc0533638e4e2df3f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f4")
    }
]
    }
  }
}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: err
    })
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "successfully updated"
      })
  }
});
```

now my db looks like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23d"), 
 "students" : [
    {
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a56fd3a02a50271d233a92f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23f")
    }, 
    {
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a65ce5cc0533638e4e2df3f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a66de1c69493c323d83a23e")
    }, 
    {
        "comments" : "not bad", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(50), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a56fd3a02a50271d233a92f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f5")
    }, 
    {
        "comments" : "good", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(100), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a65ce5cc0533638e4e2df3f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f4")
    }
]
```

i need to find the studentId in the array and then update. but here all data can push into the array.
so can anyone please tell how to find by id in the array of object and update with that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and provide `students` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that **$addToSet** is used to add onto an array, what you need to use is **$set**

```
student.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: req.body.id
}, {
  "$set": {
    "students": [
    {
        "comments" : "not bad", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(50), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a56fd3a02a50271d233a92f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f5")
    }, 
    {
        "comments" : "good", 
        "marks" : NumberInt(100), 
        "studentId" : ObjectId("5a65ce5cc0533638e4e2df3f"), 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6709d49fb0e54697b9d7f4")
    }
    ]
  }
}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: err
    })
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "successfully updated"
      })
  }
});
```